# Javascript conditional callbacks

Tags: javascript, random, callback

I'm currently using javascript to do some experiments and although I'm not new to JS I have a doubt that I hope the good folks at SO will be able to help.

Basically I'm making a jsonp request to a webservice that returns me the amount/length on the reply (just counting objects).
Then I'm randomly selecting 9 of those objects to place in an array and here lies the problem. I would like to make sure that none of those 9 objects is repeated.
To achieve this I'm using the following code:

```
function randomizer() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random()*badges.length);
}

function dupsVerify(array, number) {
    array.forEach(function () {
        if(array === number) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

// Randomly choose 9 array indexes
var randomBadge = function () {
var selectedIndexes = new Array();

while(selectedIndexes.length < 9) {
    var found = false;
    var randomNumber = randomizer();

    if(!dupsVerify(selectedIndexes, randomNumber)) {
        selectedIndexes.push(randomNumber);
    } else {
        newRandom = randomizer();
        dupsVerify(selectedIndexes, newRandom);
    }
}
return selectedIndexes;
}
```

I've tried a couple different methods of doing this verification but I've been thinking if it wouldn't be possible to do the following:

Generate the random number and go through the array to verify if it already exists in the array. If it exists, generate another random number (randomize call) and verify again.. If it doesn't exist in the array, then push it to the "final" array.

How can I achieve this? Using callbacks?
Am I doing this right or should I chance the code? Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Best Regards,

Comment: Usually a really good way to do this is to create an array containing the numbers 0 through the length of the original data array, shuffle it, and then just use the shuffled array to get 9 indexes to use. The first nine will be random and won't overlap, because you started with an array of non-overlapping values.

Comment: This is more of a code-review question. Voted to close for that reason

Comment: @Pointy, I'm doing that a bit further down the code but to generate a second array with the same indexes, but shuffled. This is because I'm making a memory game so I chose 9 initial objects, then duplicate them and shuffle them. Something like this:[49, 20, 13, 84, 72, 63, 62, 5, 49]
[49, 20, 84, 72, 62, 5, 63, 49, 13]

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It's not really a matter of code review but more a matter of the most efficient/simplest way to achieve an objective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the best solution for this scenario by using the following code:

```
function randomizer() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random()*badges.length);
}

function dupsVerify(array, number) {
    var result;
    if(array.length === 0) {result = false;}
        array.forEach(function (item) {
            if(item === number) {
                result = true;
            } else {
                result = false;
            }
        });
    return result;
}

// Randomly choose 9 array indexes
function randomBadge() {

    while(cards.length < 9) {
        var randomNumber = randomizer();
        if(!dupsVerify(cards, randomNumber)) {
            cards.push(randomNumber);
        } else {
            randomBadge();
        }
    }
    return cards;
}
```

This represents the same behavior (and a few minor code corrections) but ensures that I will never get an array with 2 repeated objects.

Answer (score 3):

This would get you the desired behavior:

```
function getRandomPositions(sourcearray, desiredcount){
   var result = [];

   while(result.lentgth < desiredcount){
       var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random()*sourcearray.length);
       if (result.indexOf(rnd) == -1){
            result.push(rnd);
       }
   }
    return result;
}
```

Instead of generating X random numbers, just generate a random number, but don't add it if it already exists.

Comment: Hi @Kenneth, that is a possible solution, but not one for my use case :)